# ArcGIS JavaScript accessing individual layer entries

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

As a newbie to ArcGIS and Javascript as a whole, I might be going about this problem the wrong way, especially seeing the samples given. However, I will still try to see if my ideal method is eligible.

In my ArcGIS file, I would like to individually isolate the entries of a FeatureLayer and modify them, mid-runtime. In this case, I would want to hide certain entries, based on their content.

```
function changeVisibility () 
{
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("expLayer");

  for (var i = 0; i < featureLayer.length; i++) 
  {
    featureLayer[i].visible = checkBox.checked;
  }
}
```

The above code is incorrect as featureLayer, which is my "FeatureLayer" type, is not an array. I'm currently searching for a method to gather the individual values of featureLayer.

The sample programs that the ESRI website gives has all the separate entries isolated into different layer classes (lake entries are separated from city entries), and then choosing to make the whole layer visible or invisible. Its making me think that isolating entries of a layer isn't possible. Even if it is possible, I'm unsure if each layer entry would have their own "visible" flag.

Is it possible to isolate the individual values of a layer class, and if so, does it take the form of an array?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript version 3 or 4?

Comment: I am using version 4.8.

Comment: By "isolate the entries of a FeatureLayer" do you mean the actual Features (the points, lines, or polygons) or are you talking more about a "Sub-layer" type thing?

Comment: I am referring to the points that I'm adding to the map/layer.